# How to refresh a particular division while using MVC

Tags: c#, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have tried different ways to refresh a particular division in MVC. 
1. Using HTML Action Link
2. Ajax Action Link
3.  method
Please help me resolve this issue.

My Code is as follows:

```
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script>
    function updateAsyncCategoryUpdate() {
        var url = '/Home/HomePage';

        $.ajax({
            url: url,

            //data: { value: '1234' }, //if there are any parameters
            dataType: "html", //or some other type
            success: function () {
                window.location.reload(true);
                // or something in that area, maybe with the 'data'
            },
            error: function () {
                //some derp
            }
        });
    }
</script>`
```

---

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(item.Name, "HomePage", new { CATEGORy = item.Name }, new AjaxOptions {HttpMethod="GET", OnSuccess = "updateAsyncCategoryUpdate('item.Name')" })
```

Comment: `success: function (data) { $(someDiv).html(data); }`

Answer (score 1):

You can append the success function.

This replaces content of div

```
success: function (data) 
{ 
    $('#divSelector').html(data); 
}
```

This appends content of div

```
 success: function (data) 
 { 
    $('#divSelector').append(data); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script function does not have parameter and you send Item.Name to it.(although you dont use this parameter inside the script!)

First, define parameter for  updateAsyncCategoryUpdate function.

Secomd,Add a container element(like div) to your page with specific id(resultDiv for example) and replace the success code of your scrip with this:

```
success: function(result){
var myDiv = $('#resultDiv');
myDiv.empty();
myDiv.prepend(result);
}
```